# google-play-services-lib doesnt working with my maps project

Tags: android

Hi people i´m a very begginer developing android apps and i want to do some application using the google maps android api v2, but with no succes.
The step im following are this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/ testing it with a samsung galaxy SIII phonel.
The application simply starts but close inmediatly (5 seconds after) telling the app must be closed.
Attached you can find the logcat with the errors and here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tuxido.example.mapuse"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <permission
        android:name="tuxido.example.mapuse.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="tuxido.example.mapuse.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"    android:value="(my API key)" />
</manifest>
```

I added the google-services-lin in the workspace as in the tutorial
Thanks before hand

Answer (score 0):

Your meta-data elements should be within the application element.  See previous [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920996/google-maps-apiv2-unable-to-run-in-google-nexus7/20921323#20921323).  By the way, don't show your API Key.

I am adding one of my manifests from a working program (less the API key of course)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NextActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_next" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="....."/>        
</application>
```

Comment: If you have both (2) meta-data elements within the application element, then your manifest is okay.  But there is still the xml and the java files and I cannot comment about these because I've not seen them.  Just to make sure of things, please edit your original to show your new manifest file.